# How to add an face image to a video using php

Tags: php, html5-video, video-capture, video-editing

Im creating a Web App and i wanted to know how to add a face image to a video.
The image will be attached to video with "Sign Up with Facebook"(No problem with this)
I think there's a way to code it with PHP or something else

This is a referal 
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/santa-hq-elfie/id935702306?mt=8

Any suggestion or a Link will be very helpful

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just using PHP, because PHP in itself doesn't provide the necessary libraries for recording editing videos.

To edit video you'll need ffmpeg (there is PHP extension) installed on your server. You can then access these programmes by using the the exec() function in PHP.

https://github.com/PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg

Another alternative is to use the angularjs and classes Video Editor to create the video (https://github.com/moviemasher/angular-moviemasher).

I think you have to develop your own video creator, I dont know a ready solution via html5 or php, so you need develop.